# XslCompiledTransform not Resolving import in Powershell

Tags: powershell, xslt

Using Powershell, I'm trying load an XSLT file in memory, modify and use it in a transform, but i keep on getting "XSLT compile errors". the XSLT file contains imports (xsl:import href=), when i made the path absolute, it started working, however, that is not ideal. All files are in the same directory.

```
$processor = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$settings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings;
$resolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver;
[xml]$xsltdoc = Get-Content "transformMe.xslt"

# do some xml manipulations....

$processor.Load($xsltdoc, $settings, $resolver);

# I left out some things here to keep the code simple but the error happens on Load()
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `Get-Content ".\transformMe.xslt"`? If you don't want an absolute path is a relative path ok?

Comment: i can load the xslt into a variable just fine, because i am able to manipulate it.  The error occurs in $processor.Load()

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the absolute path bit. I'm headed home but I'll think about it on the bus ride and check back when I get in tomorrow in case nobody has gotten this resolved for you by then.

Comment: i was able to workaround the issue by updating the import href to an absolute path in POWERSHELL as i manipulate the XML. However, i wish the XMLUrlResolver just worked. I welcome better solutions.

Comment: I am not familiar with Powershell, what does `[xml]$xsltdoc = Get-Content "transformMe.xslt"` exactly do? Does it call the `Load` method of an `XmlDocument`? I think in that case the BaseURI would be set correctly and the XmlUrlResolver could do its job. But if it uses the `LoadXml` method after reading in the file contents as a string then the BaseURI is not set. So you would either need to make sure your own code sets it or instead of working with `Get-Content` you would create an `XmlDocument` and call its `Load("transformMe.xslt")` method.

Comment: Hmm, I have just seen that BaseURI is a readonly property so you can't set it. In that case you have to try to load the stylesheet with the Load method.

Comment: @martin, i'll try that. i've moved onto another task and have to loop back in a couple days.